# How can I get text from a text box and do something with that with JavaScript in WordPress page?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I'm trying to make a page in WordPress that contains a text box and a button. by clicking on the button get the text that entered in the text box(I don't want to save that text) and enter that text to an specific site address.

I don't know how to do it, please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by specific site address?

Comment: i have this address http://newtracking.post.ir/?id=   after the =  i want to enter the text from textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the HTML with the proper `onclick`

```
<input type="text" id="mytext">
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://newtracking.post.ir/?id=' + document.getElementById('mytext').value;">
```

EDIT

This is how you can apply URL parameters where the name of the parameters are ids. You can assume `mytext` to be the id if you prefer, of course.

```
var url = window.location.href;
if (url.indexOf("?") > 0) {
    var params = url.substring(url.indexOf("?") + 1).split("&");
    for (let param of params) {
        let key = param.substring(0, param.indexOf("="));
        let value = param.substring(param.indexOf("=") + 1);
        let element = document.getElementById(key);
        if (element) element.value = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks thats worked but i have other problem. iwant to fill this text box with a value from address bar like some thing i did in this : http://newtracking.post.ir/?id=my_value  but icant do the same in my site i tried this but didnt fill the text box : https://itadim.com/tracking/?mytext=my_value this my page: https://itadim.com/tracking/ can you help me please?

Comment: @SajadAmiri that's also achievable, please take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: thanks for your help again. you really helped me.